# distinguishing between forwarding addresses and non-copied objects in stop and copy garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection

I've read many descriptions of the semispace stop-and-copy collector, and they all have one step in common:

> If the pointer points to an object in fromspace, that object is evacuated. But if the pointer points to a forwarding address, the object has already been evacuated, so the old address is simply replaced with the new address.

How does one distinguish whether a pointer points to a forwarding address as opposed to a non-copied object? I've seen numerous claims that stop-and-copy doesn't need a block header, but I don't see how to distinguish the two choices without one. Every description I've read handwaves the issue as "if the target is a forwarding address", without describing how to tell if the target is a forwarding address or not.

For example, I took a look at an implementation here: https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/4736334
And it appears to be cheating, by using an extra field "forwardingAddress". That isn't the block-header-free implementation I was led to believe existed.

The only solution I can think of right now is that the garbage collector is conservative instead of precise. But again, nothing I've read has suggested that the stop-and-copy collector is not precise.

Comment: If the first word of each object is certainly a pointer (as opposed to an integer), isn't it enough to check if it points into the to-space? That is, `start_of_tospace <= p && p < end_of_tospace`

Comment: But then, you'd have to know that the first word is "certainly a pointer". Which isn't true for arbitrary objects; you'd need a block header.

Comment: In many languages, it is true. For example, Java-style object orientation needs type information (unrelated to garbage collection!) which is convenient and efficient to store in the first word.

Comment: I see; that is the answer to my question. Thanks for the help!